# What type of device is required to view emmc chip on Linux

Tags: dump

I have emmc I want to read on Linux, what kind of devices can read emmc on Linux ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, any devices with a Linux-supported eMMC host controller chip of course!

The bigger problem is that eMMCs are typically not considered user-removable components, as they are normally directly soldered on the motherboard. And if they are Ball-Grid Array (BGA) components, soldering them requires special skill and equipment.

If what you actually have is not just an eMMC *chip*, but an eMMC *module* intended to be used with the ODROID family of single-board computers, then all you'll is need a high-speed MicroSD card reader and an inexpensive adapter like this: https://www.hardkernel.com/shop/emmc-module-reader-board-for-os-upgrade/

Schematic for an adapter between an ODROID eMMC module connector and a MicroSD card socket: https://dn.odroid.com/eMMCModule/eMMC_Reader.png

Schematic for the actual ODROID eMMC module: https://dn.odroid.com/eMMCModule/EMMC_REV0.4.pdf

If you got an eMMC module for some other product, the module interface could be vendor-specific, since as far as I know, there is no standard for eMMC module interfaces. You might have to try and figure out the schematic of your actual module to verify it uses the same pinout, even if it seems to use the same connector.

Comment: Thanks for that, the it’s just a emmc bag soldered, I do know the pinout to read in the board, like the clk,cmd,d0 etc, berg if I have to remove the emmc then that’s not a issue as I can do bga work, don’t really know what device can read it in Linux